# Are access macros supported on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, database, access

I am working on building an Access 2013 database that I'd like to deploy on our SharePoint 2013 Online site.

I'd like to do some VBA customization but am concerned it will not work like excel's macros do not work on SharePoint.

**Are access macros supported on SharePoint?**

If you have any other advice or information for creating and deploying an access database on SharePoint online, I'd appreicate it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not an answer to say macros works on SharePoint online. Just wanted to give you an update on Microsoft roadmap on Access App.

The Microsoft is no longer recommending Access Apps. This feature will be retired from Office 365 and SharePoint Online. Microsoft will stop the creation of new Access-based apps and Access web databases in Office 365 and SharePoint Online starting in June 2017 and shut down any remaining apps and web databases by April 2018.

Power Apps are the alternate way and feature. Site to learn [Power Apps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/).

You can read complete article [Access service in SharePoint Roadmap.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-Services-in-SharePoint-Roadmap-497fd86b-e982-43c4-8318-81e6d3e711e8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: I was actually just typing up an answer with this information as I think it is an answer! SharePoint won't support Access apps so it won't support Access macros ;-) Do you have experience working with PowerApps?

Comment: We have created samples but not been published for users.